# If a midi tempo change occur, will it change all remaining tempo change's time?

Tags: c++, file, midi

I'm decoding midi files now, it is not simple, but anyway I want to do it for myself.
I know that tempo change affects all tracks, but I'm just think that it affects all upcoming tempo changes's time. I'm just want to sure before I accept that theory.

Comment: Your question could be clearer. IIRC tempo changes go with an absolute (BPM) parameter, so it would last up till the next tempo change, if you ask me. But you could easily just test this with a midi player

Comment: I agree with that question is not clear. "all remaining tempo change's  time is" is meant to be: "all tempo change after this one in timeline" and tempo change's time is: "the tempo change's realtime".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to correct the comment by @sehe, MIDI tempo changes do not use BPM for their units, though they are absolute. Tempo changes use [microseconds per quarter note](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile.htm), not beats per minute.

That said, MIDI tempo changes are not relative to each other, so you don't need to worry about tempo changes effecting each other. Or to give an example, say you have three tempo changes in your sequence:

```
A=110 BPM ..... B=120 BPM ...... C=140 BPM
```

And you remove `B` from the sequence, the tempo will still be 140 BPM when you reach `C`. Hope that answers your question!

Comment: It's correct answer for my question. Anyway, the question was wrong.

Comment: I'm glad you had the details :_ Thx for sharing